# Apache warning: RWX mapping denied when calling clamav through php-clamav

Tags: php, apache, centos7, antivirus, selinux

I have a CentOS 7 server with SELinux, Apache2, ClamAV and php-clamav installed and configured.

Everything is working nice (after a lot of struggling with SELinux), apart from the fact I keep getting this annoying message in the error log whever I initialize clamAV from Apache (via php-clamav):

> LibClamAV Warning: RWX mapping denied: Can't allocate RWX Memory: Permission denied
>   LibClamAV Warning: Bytecode: disabling JIT because SELinux is preventing 'execmem' access.
>   Run  'setsebool -P clamd_use_jit on'.

Also, every clamav script call is taking exactly 9 seconds, even cl_info(); or scanning a blank or nonexistent file which seems a long time to me, on a quad core, 2 gb ram server.

I already configured SELinux booleans antivirus_can_scan_system and antivirus_use_jit to ON. I even tried to set httpd_use_cifs to ON, to no effect, so I reverted to OFF to avoid security risks.

Obviously, I searched the Internet wide to understand the issue, learned a lot about SELinux, but I still can't get httpd call to clamd to use JIT. I almost resorted to disable clamd JIT entirely, but I would prefer to allow it instead, if (as I understand) this would make performances better.

Please give me some hint about what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, RH devs claim the JIT is implemented insecurely, which is why they don't enable this without specific selinux enablement.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=573191